# interpreting function within a function in scala

Tags: scala

I'm new to scala, and I see this piece of code:

```
def sum(f: Int => Int)(a: Int, b: Int): Int = ...
```

I know that this sum function takes a function with 2 parameters(a and b) of type Ints.

Am I correct to say that:

The **sum** function takes a function, because i see **(f:** after **def sum**?

I'm a bit confused with the **Int => Int** syntax and the last **:Int** before **=**.

What does the **Int** on the left of the right arrow indicate?

Does the Int type on the right of the right arrow indicate:

- the return value of the **sum** function?
- or does it indicate the return value of the anonymous function

does the last **:Int =** indicate the return value of **sum** function is of type Int??

Answer (score 0):

The `sum` method takes 3 parameters, split between two lists, and returns an `Int`. The first parameter list is for a function that takes an `Int` and returns an `Int`. That makes `sum` a higher-order function (in the loose sense of equating methods and functions). The colon means "of type".

It's significant to note that there is a different syntax for return values of functions and methods. This is because functions are values in Scala, and therefore their arguments and return types must be captured by a single type, and the `=>` captures this. Methods are not values, and their parameter types and return types are notated separately. You may be able to gloss over this as a beginner, but I think it's worthwhile to [explore the distinction](http://jim-mcbeath.blogspot.com/2009/05/scala-functions-vs-methods.html).